# consuming .Net DataSet by REST java

Tags: java, .net, rest, dataset

I have to write a REST client to consume a service written in .Net. The problem is that the .Net service returns a gzip compressed serialized DataSet. How do I parse it? I have seen other solutions explaining how to do it using SOAP (I have to use REST). Another solution says to write a .Net proxy. But my deployment server is a linux machine with limited access so I may not have the luxury of using tools like Mono.

The folks exposing service haven't provided any wsdl specs. Just given ways to construct URLs that when invoked will return what I need. So what's my way forward :

1. Try SOAP? Is that even possible? I have no wsdl info. So I assumed it will be REST.
2. Create a .Net proxy that consumes this service and converts to more readable xml, and find ways to make this .Net exe run on linux?
3. Continue searching for a solution/library that can read DataSet? I have been developing clients using Spring RestTemplate which doesn't seem to work here.

Also, accessing the URL from Advanced Rest client shows that Content-Type: compressed/DataSet

Answer (score 1):

So I had to end up creating a .Net proxy that decompresses and deserializes the DataSet response, convert to xml and save at a shared location from where Java program can pick up.